Scrapy scraping all pages in domain
I'm tearing my hair out trying to get scrapy to look at all pages in a domain.  I tried the rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True)] way (instead of the dragon_start function in my code), and didn't get anywhere.  Now I'm trying to extract all links and iterate on that list, and that's not working either.  What am I failing to do!  Copilot isn't helping, and I looked at pretty much all the other SO posts...
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy import Request

class DvSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "dvspider"
    start_urls = ["https://dragonvale.fandom.com/wiki/Dragons"]
    allowed_domains = ["dragonvale.fandom.com/wiki"]

    def dragon_start(self, response):
        links = response.css('a::attr(href)').extract()
        for link in links:
            yield Request(response.urljoin(link), self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        if response.url[-7] == '_':
            dragon = response.css('table.dragonbox')

            if dragon:
                rows = dragon.xpath('//tr')
                yield {
                    'DragonName': rows[0].css('b::text').get().strip(),
                }

I don't get any errors, and scrapy crawls start_urls with a (200) code.  But then the spider immediately says INFO: Closing spider (finished).

I think you are missing the start_requests entry point.
For example,
from typing import Iterable
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy import Request

class DvSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "dvspider"
    start_urls = ["https://dragonvale.fandom.com/wiki/Dragons"]
    allowed_domains = ["dragonvale.fandom.com/wiki"]

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(self.start_urls[0], self.dragon_start)

    def dragon_start(self, response):
        links = response.css('a::attr(href)').extract()
        for link in links:
            yield Request(response.urljoin(link), self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        if response.url[-7] == '_':
            dragon = response.css('table.dragonbox')

            if dragon:
                rows = dragon.xpath('//tr')

                yield {
                    'DragonName': rows[0].css('b::text').get().strip(),
                }

This should call the dragon_start function and start iterating the links from there.

At this point you can replace CrawlSpider with Spider as you aren't using any of the CrawlSpider features, and then remove start_requests again as it's not needed.
